# Not able to install xcode 4.5.1 from itunes

Tags: installation, xcode4.5

ok.. i had xcode 4.2 installed on my mac. I had installed this using the dmg file and not itunes. i want to install xcode 4.5.1 available on itunes. i started the download of it and the download got stuck at one point. i realized that i had not uninstalled the previous one. so i paused the download and uninstalled existing xcode using terminal commands. now i try to install the xcode again from itunes and it does not go beyond install.

[image]

i dunno what to do and how to install.. i tried quitting itunes helper, yet didnt help with the installation. Any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the installer is through the app store.  4.5.1 was released Oct 3.  I'm still trying to install it as well.  I'm sure it has been on my update liste 2 or 3 times in a row.

Good luck!